# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax/el/ValueExpression in Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, jstl, tomcat5.5

I had my Spring app (webapp ver 2.5) running well on Tomcat 6.0. However, after I converted it to webapp ver 2.4 to run on Tomcat 5.5, I came across the below exception:

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax/el/ValueExpression
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax/el/ValueExpression
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:774)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1287)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1285)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1151)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:402)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:229)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:383)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:229)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:383)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3729)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2132)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1600)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1706)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1706)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3321)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:171)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f1(index_jsp.java:186)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ValueExpression
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1363)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1209)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1287)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1285)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1151)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:402)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:229)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:383)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:229)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:383)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:168)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3729)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2132)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1600)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1706)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1706)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3321)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:171)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f1(index_jsp.java:186)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I have reference to JSTL library like below:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

My library has the below jars:

```
asm-3.1.jar
cglib-2.1.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
jersey-client-1.8.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-json-1.8.jar
jersey-server-1.8.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
mail-1.4.1.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
standard-1.0.4.jar
velocity-1.6.jar
```

As I learned from other posts, it has got something to do with jstl, and that jstl-1.2.jar is incompatible. However, with jstl-1.1.2, jstl-1.1.1 and jstl-1.1.0 I get an error **Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"** in jsp. I think this can be resolved by adding c.tld and other tld files and having a reference to these files in web.xml. For that I think I need to add them to tomcat folder, which I don't have access to (I'm on shared Tomcat).

I added/removed the below jars as required to fix this problem, but there's one exception or the other.

```
el-api-6.0.20.jar
jstl-1.1.0.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar
jstl-impl-1.2.jar
```

Anybody knows the solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think that you can update the el-api jar of an tomcat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your `/WEB-INF/lib` listing:

> ```
> jstl-1.2.jar
> ```

This JAR contains *both* the JSTL 1.2 API and implementation, which in turn requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 / JSP/EL 2.1. The `javax.el` package was introduced in JSP/EL 2.1, but Tomcat 5.5 doesn't support it, which thus explains the exception you posted in the question.

> ```
> standard-1.0.4.jar
> ```

This JAR contains the JSTL 1.0 implementation and taglibs. This actually requires a JSTL 1.0 API JAR file along it. The taglib URI of JSTL 1.0 is also different, it doesn't contain `/jsp` in the URI, which thus explains the taglib URI error you got when replacing JSTL 1.2 API/impl by JSTL 1.1 API (no, the JSTL 1.1 API libs don't contain the impl!).

Tomcat 5.5 is a Servlet 2.4 container which works with JSTL 1.1 only. You need to remove **both** of the above mentioned JARs (JSTL 1.2 API/impl and JSTL 1.0 impl) and then replace it with the two JARs of JSTL 1.1 which you can download [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip). It are the `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` which you can find in the `/lib` folder of the ZIP file.